# How to pass any character through the url rewrite mechanism, within the url path, as a value

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, escaping

I have a rather intricate url escaping problem.

I have in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site/index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

...and if this and index.php sit on localhost/site/, all urls starting with localhost/site/ will correctly forward to index.php, and I can see/parse the requested url using `$_GET["path"]` or `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. This allows me to create nice looking urls like:

```
localhost/site/
localhost/site/user/sarah
localhost/site/user/sarah/edit/my-recent-article
localhost/site/user/sarah/settings
...
```

This all works. Fine so far.

The problem is, I now want the username to be potentially *anything*: any utf character (including spaces, slashes (!), etc). This is where the problem starts.

I have to encode the username TWICE using rawurlencode(), before presenting it to the browser. Some sample cases that I use, for reference:

```
$aTests = array(
        "/user/".rawurlencode("Heizölrückstoßabdämpfung")."/sdf",
        "/user/".rawurlencode("Zwölf Boxkämpfer jagten Eva quer über den Sylter Deich")."/sdf",
        "/user/".rawurlencode("? דג סקרן שט בים מאוכזב ולפתע מצא לו חברה איך הקליטה")."/sdf",
        "/user/".rawurlencode("イロハニホヘト チリヌルヲ ワカヨタレソ ツネナラム")."/sdf",
        "/user/".rawurlencode("!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:@;<=>?[\\]^_`{|} ~")."/sdf",
        "/user/".rawurlencode("http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/")."/sdf",
        "/user/".rawurlencode("encoded/once")."/sdf",
        "/user/".rawurlencode(rawurlencode("encoded/twice"))."/sdf",
);

foreach ($aTests as $sTest) {
    echo "<a href='http://localhost/site".htmlEntities($sTest, ENT_QUOTES)."'>http://localhost/site".htmlspecialchars($sTest, ENT_QUOTES)."</a><br />";
}
```

All the test cases work fine, EXCEPT when a username calls himself "http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/" or "encoded/once" or "!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:@;<=>?[\]^_`{|} ~" in the above test case. The slash (and apparently other characters in the latter) seem to break the browser, and I get a "404 Not Found, The requested URL /site/user/encoded/once/sdf was not found on this server.". The two cases of double escaping work.

I figured (but I am *not* sure!) that EITHER: The rewrite rule does not escape the (whole) url, so you have to do it once for safely embedding the string (username) into the url, and another time to pass it correctly through the rewrite mechanism, OR: The Apache server stops if it finds a slash in the url (I read this somewhere, but I don't understand if this is my case (no information in the logs), or what the security concerns are why apache has this behaviour, if applicable).

I don't like escaping strings twice before presenting it to the browser (an un-ideal situation: people start sharing urls with double escaped, bad looking strings). I want the .htaccess mechanism to escape the complete url during the rewrite appropriately for me.

I am using Apache 2.4.6, but the answer should hopefully apply to a wide area of servers...

Did someone have a similar situation/setup, and what was your solution?

**Edit2**: I found out that I had to enable `AllowEncodedSlashes On` (be cautious when enabling this, there are associated security concerns (related to accidental tree-traversal etc.)), then the page works for all cases. Note that this needs to be enabled in httpd.conf, not .htaccess, which limits it to host-specific deployments. *But this is not the end of the question.* From `$_GET["path"]`, I am receiving "user/encoded/once/sdf", when I should be receiving "user/encoded%2Fonce/sdf" (as this is what I am printing on the page). Clearly, some unexpected pre-decoding is still occurring. `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is however containing "site/user/encoded%2Fonce/sdf" correctly. One could use this already.